# getting principal object in spring security even after using setAuthenticated(false)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am authenticating the loggedin user using `UserNamePasswordAuthentictionToken`.

But after that on some condition i want to log out manually. Inside if condition I have put the below code. I am getting `authenticated=false`, but principal object still remains there..

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
    .setAuthenticated(false);
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null)`.

`authenticated` is just a boolean flag beside the principal object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your version of Spring, but still you can also add:

```
SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();

if( currentUser == null ) {
    logoutHandler.logout(request, response, auth);
}
```

next after to call of clearContext();

Comment: thanks for your reply..after authenticating I am getting the current user using UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) auth.getPrincipal(); and then I am setting setauthenticated(false). iam getting authentication=false..but still able to find the the current user using  UserInfo user=(UserInfo)auth.getPrincipal(); in some another method...so do I need to manually set UserInfo user=null..as u have mentioned above..please reply

Comment: I understand what do you mean, but did you try above code? Could you confirm that even after this code you are able to obtain UserInfo?

Comment: thank you for reply. but in your code you have put if(currentUser=null). but in my case current user is there. should I manually set UserInfo==null, and then try this method suggested by you.

Comment: I suppose you could try setting UserInfo == null.